# How to get access virtual servers from host machine by domain?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, virtualhost, host

I have virtual machine Ubuntu on Windows host machine. On VM there is `nginx` server with virtual server `site.com`. VM IP is `127.0.1.1`. In VM I edit `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1 site.com www.site.com
```

And now I can type in VM browser `site.com` and get site access. But I want the same on the host machine. I edited Windows `hosts` file with:

```
127.0.1.1 site.com www.site.com
```

But with no result.

- My VM name has `linserver` name and in Windows `http://linserver` open default virtual server (`site.com`, now it's only).
- `http://127.0.1.1` not working.

VM is `VMWare`. Virtual Network adapter is `NAT`, trying change to `Bridged` but with the same no result.

Comment: VM is a computer on its own with its own network address. It's not a "localhost" which any `127.x.x.x` refers to. Use the IP address that is assigned to the VM. NAT (a.k.a. "user mode networking") certainly complicates things; you need to forward port to your VM. Also, the sole use of the NAT makes the question to not look like it's about running VMs in a business environment. Looks like it's your personal VM. This kind of questions better asked on SuperUser.

Comment: Yeah, you absolutely right about that `127.0.1.1` thing — I'm already understand it and now searching information in that direction. And yes, I just doing first steps in web, so it's test VM for learning. Take into account about SuperUser. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `127.0.1.1` writing correct IP-address of VM in Windows `hosts` and now it works fine.